# Am looking to run a python script on a remote machine which connects to a mysql database

Tags: python, mysql

basically i want to connect to the mysql (through Python), run a python script on the mysql server that checks whether a certain table has any entries....if it does't then it sends an sms through a SMS API gateway

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. What is your question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a place to ask more specific code questions, not describe a high-level problem and get people to write your code for you. You should read the [Help Center pages on asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score -1):

A connection to a mysql Database is possible and easy with pymyslq. When you are connected to the Database you can make a request if the table is empty and send your sms